# How to Fill a set of elements through a JTable column elements?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, set

I am trying to fill a set of double elements, with the elements stocked in a  JTable column, I tried with a "for" loop but the algorithm is not relevant:

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
 {
     double ad [ ] = { (double)dtm.getValueAt(i, 1)};
 }
```

The problem is that when the "i" variable gets equal to a new value (1 or two for example) the last value is replaced by the new value.

What algorithm does allow to fill the set?

Comment: Right now you are using an array. Do you want to use a set or an array?

Comment: I want to have a result like this ad [] ={1, 4, 5, 8, 9....etc} it's just an example but it's the kind of result i hope to get at last , given that the numbers between curly brackets stocked in a table

Comment: In Java, those {} mean an array (__not__ a set like math). Arrays have a fixed size and you have to add indices. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

thanks @camick and @madprogrammer updated the code this could be optimal according to requirements.

```
public Object[] getColumnData(JTable table, int targetColIndex) {
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
if(table== null)
    return null;
if(targetColIndex > nCol)
    return null;
Object[] tableData = new Object[nRow];
for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
   tableData[i] = dtm.getValueAt(i,targetColIndex);
return tableData;
}
```

Hi check the above might help you.

Comment: Kind of overkill since the op is only getting the values from the first column

Comment: If you look at the OPs last 2 questions you will see that the OP needs data for 3 different columns in the table. So this is the right approach, but your method should receive the table and the column index and just return an Array for that column. Then then method can be invoked 3 times. Fix the method and you get an up vote from me.

Comment: Well, the requirement was to return double values in the Array, not Objects but I up voted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign each element of the array an individual value, for example...

```
TableModel dtm = ...;
int nRow = dtm.getRowCount();
double ad[] = new double[nRow];
for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
{
    ad[i] = (double)dtm.getValueAt(i, 1);
}
```

See [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details